# Place images in the gap where text it padded

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a vertical banner on either side of some text using some images. I'm currently using padding to keep the text in place but I would like the padding to be ignored for the image placement but not the text.

Currently the image is either part of the text or pushes the text even further to the wrong direction.

```css
.body{
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #231427;
}
.body > .images{
  padding-left: -20%;
  padding-right: -20%;
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #231427;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas porta consectetur nisl, sed porta enim ullamcorper eu. Ut id vulputate sem, ac fringilla ligula.</p>
<br>
<div class="images">
  <img src="img/IMG_3502.JPG" alt="W. Jons Property" width="170px">
</div>
```

Comment: so you want the text to placed next to image?

Comment: could u elaborate more? I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: can you show us desired output? I don't fully understand the issue here

Comment: So currently the images are displayed above where the text begins and I would two columns of images to be displayed across the left and the right of the text, sorry for any ambiguity @ArianShahalami

Comment: @trezremay you can create a sketch in Paint or something because its hard to understand

Comment: @OmriAttiya https://imgur.com/a/RxMvHRD i would like the pictures to display where the drawn squares are - thank you for being patient with me

Comment: can you add the image in the question itself? my ofc laptop is not allowing to view it!

Comment: sorry @Manjuboyz in not entirely sure how to do that in a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex` for your requirement.

```css
.body {
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #231427;
}

#MainDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.images {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #231427;
}
```

```html
<div id="MainDiv">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="images">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" alt="W. Jons Property" width="100px">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas porta consectetur nisl, sed porta enim ullamcorper eu. Ut id vulputate sem, ac fringilla ligula.</p>
    <br>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="images">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" alt="W. Jons Property" width="100px">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas porta consectetur nisl, sed porta enim ullamcorper eu. Ut id vulputate sem, ac fringilla ligula.</p>
    <br>
  </div>



</div>
```